# Nuget restores packages differently on build server

Tags: msbuild, nuget

The local dev machines restore the package like this:

> ..\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.2.1.1\..

but the build server when it restores the nuget packages it changes some of them to

> ..\microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets\2.1.1\..

with lower-case and changing the folder structure. When MSBuild executes for the solution, it can't find the required files because the folder structure is different.
I think it might be a nuget.config issue but I am uncertain.

Edit: The csproj file has a condition that is checking to see if the underlying dependency (microsoft.extensions.configuration.usersecrets) is in the correct folder path. If it is not in the correct folder path, then it is throwing a build error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the condition check for the particular nuget reference completely from the csproj file, I check to confirm that the package is not in either folder structure location so that it will support both developer and build environments.

Answer (score 0):

A packages folder using the structure `packages\PackageId.Version\` I believe is a "v2" feed, whereas `packages\packageid\version\` is a "v4" feed. When NuGet adds packages to a feed, it tries to detect the feed version before adding new packages, and defaults to V2 feeds for packages.config projects. The global packages folder should always be V4, but packages.config projects are restored to a solution packages folder which is normally V2.

So my guess is your solution has packages.config projects, but the solution packages folder is not empty on the build server and NuGet is detecting it as a v4 feed, rather than a v2 feed.

I suggest making sure that the solution packages folder points to a folder within your repo. Setting it to something like ..\packages to escape your repo means there's an increased risk of other builds that run on the build agent before your build will affect you. Alternatively, your build script could delete the solution packages folder before doing a restore to make sure that anything already in there don't negatively affect your build.

If these suggestions don't help, it would be useful to know what version of nuget is being used on the build server and what you're using on your local machine.

Comment: The nuget versions are 4.6 on both machines. I've changed the feed url's to v2 and v3 api's but no success. I clear out the cache and delete all the packages to no avail.